# OnBase Advanced Capture: How to use VBScript to get the image of a zone being scanned?

Tags: ocr, onbase

The OnBase Advanced Capture OCR engine returns an object to the VBScript called OCRDoc. Under this object, there's a method called GetImageSnippets:

```
GetImageSnippets(VARIANT vPathTemplate, VARIANT vPathCurrent)
```

However, I cannot find where to obtain the values for these parameters: vPathTemplate and vPathCurrent.

Where can I find the values of these parameters so that I can use the method to access the image being called in a Form Identification Zone?

Or is there another way to access the image being scanned in a zone using VBScript?